I initialize an array and then I see random values in it
I have the following problem when initializing an array in C. I am using an STM32 and Keil uVision IDE. The array as it is too big, it is declared in an external SDRAM memory we are using (big enough). Here is the code:
Scatter file:
SDRAM_ACQ_HARDCODED_AV 0xD0643000 0x141000{;N_DATA_ROWS_IN_N20_ALGORITHM_BUFFER
    *(.sdram_acq_hardcoded_av)
  }

C file:
#define SDRAM_ACQ_HARDCODED_AV __attribute__((section(".sdram_acq_hardcoded_av")))

SDRAM_ACQ_HARDCODED_AV const int16_t AcqRaw_StimArtifactRemoved_Buffer_By50nV_HC[14592] = {
-7154,
-7167,
-7158,
-7137,
-7122,
-7091,

.h file:
extern const int16_t AcqRaw_StimArtifactRemoved_Buffer_By50nV_HC[14592];

And when I start debugging and checking the values of this array, I see there completely random values inside the array. What is the problem here?
I have tried to see problems in the scatter file or the optimization of the code, but everything seems correct.

No matter in what RAM area the array is located, you need to have enough space in flash for the initialization data. Also, your array is defined as array holding const values. Can't you use the array directly from the flash area instead of RAM?

As I was using the external RAM because I did not want to waste flash data with that.. but now I see why it did not work hehe now it works just using the flash! Thanks for the help!

anything non-volatile has to be in flash and then copied to ram, so it is in flash, then if you want it copied to ram you burn twice as much space (for constants).  If you need the speed of ram though you put it there, you said external sdram that is not fast, so leave it in flash.

This initialization does nothing. You need to copy the data to the SDRAM after the memory controller was initialized.
The compiler will not help you with it as the startup code is executed before your program initializes the memory controller.

As already mentioned here, I think that when the initialization is executed, probably the external SDRAM is yet to be initialized, so the values written by the initialization routine aren't stored into the external SDRAM, because the SDRAM chip is not yet in operational state.
I think it would be a good idea to:

store the initialization values for your array AcqRaw_StimArtifactRemoved_Buffer_By50nV_HC into an array defined in a code section (or an equivalent const section that doesn't need initialization):

let's call the array e.g. init_array_in_code_area


then, AFTER that the SDRAM has been properly initialized, you can copy the initialization values from the init_array_in_code_area array into your AcqRaw_StimArtifactRemoved_Buffer_By50nV_HC SDRAM array.

